# Reduction of (4-methylcyclohex-3-en-1-yl)methoxymethylbenzene to 4-methylcyclohex-3-en-1-ol

Tags: organic-chemistry, organic-reduction

> Find the suitable reagent to carry out the following transformation:
>
> [image: (4-methylcyclohex-3-en-1-yl)methoxymethylbenzene → 4-methylcyclohex-3-en-1-ol]

The answer provided says that $\ce{H2/Pd-C}$ can be used to bring about the given transformation, but I am failing to understand why would the double bond remain unaffected. Moreover, the answer does not specify the number of equivalents of $\ce{H2}$ used.

Comment: You are right, they are wrong. There is no way you can carry out this hydrogenation and leave the alkene untouched.